# Ceph delete client.admin accidently

Tags: ceph

While learning Ceph , I accidently delete client.admin by using

```
ceph auth del client.admin
```

Now I get

> client.admin authentication error (1) Operation not permitted.Error connecting to cluster: PermissionError

all the time.

Is there a way to recover or recreate a new client.admin?
I've tried

`ceph auth import -i /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring` 
 and
`ceph add client.admin`

It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to connect with mon keyring on ceph-node-1

```
ceph -n mon. --keyring /var/lib/ceph/mon/ceph-node-1/keyring get-or-create client.admin mon 'allow *' mds 'allow *' mgr 'allow *' osd 'allow *'
```

then update /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring